# camera tracking an object vs animation

Tags: camera

Is it possible to switch the same camera between "tracking an object animation" and "not object tracking animation"? Or do I have to use two cameras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constraints include an ‘Influence’ property that varies between 1.0 (fully ‘on’) to 0.0 (fully ‘off’). The incluence can be keyframed so that you can vary it as desired. When you want the tracking to affect the camera you would set the influence to 1.0 and when you want to animate the camera you adjust it down to 0.0.